# Writing new values into array

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a fragment of my code:

```
typedef float point2[2];

point2 a = {-90, -90};
point2 b = {-90, 90};
point2 c = {90, 90};
point2 d = {90, -90};

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2fv(a);
    glVertex2fv(b);
    glVertex2fv(c);
    glVertex2fv(d);
glEnd();
```

And this goes really well. But later when I try to write new values into these arrays, like:

```
a = {-66, -66};
b = {-66, 66};
```

And here I get an error:

```
error: assigning to an array from an initializer list
```

And I understand, that I can't assign values directly to an array after its declaration. But how this should looks like?

Comment: Initializer lists are just usable during initialization

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very poor and you can easily find it in any textbook!!!

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, I know. But like I said - I wanted to know if there is more convinient way then just a[0]=... a[1]=...

Comment: OK then @DzikiChrzan, I will retrieve my downvote and as a sorry I will upvote an answer of yours I like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to an array using an initializer list. But if you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C array then this is possible:

```
#include <array>
typedef std::array<float, 2> point2;

point2 a = {-90.0, -90.0};
a = {-66, -66};
```

And you can still pass it to a function like `glVertex2fv` that takes a pointer to an array by using [`std::array::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data):

```
glVertex2fv(a.data());
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/h6kAwZfhZRiaPyKh)

Comment: Yeah, so there IS a way to do it different! Thanks, this is answer I was looking for. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In those statements, you are not assigning values to an array, you are initializing that array. Changing values in an array can be done like this:

```
a[0] = -66;
a[1] = -66;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant use initializer list once the array is initialized, just do:

```
a[0] = -66;
a[1] = -66;
```

Comment: first solution should work but it has unnecessary cost

Comment: @HumamHelfawi yes, I just mentioned it, because I assumed the OP already knows how to access the array elements but was looking for a denser notation.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are not objects. They don't have a constructor. And your first suggestion doesn't work, because you can't modify the pointer, to which your locally defined array variable is pointing, as well.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius hm? The locally defined array variable is not pointing to a pointer

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius but you are right, that it doesnt work, because there is no constructor to call. My mistake, I will edit

Comment: @tobi303 Arrays in C++ are pointers. Even if you don't see a pointer symbol (*), they still function as pointers would.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes but the pointer is pointing to a float isnt it?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, and your point is? The fact is - you can't change it. Compiler doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

When your case is really about points in a plain, you schould prefer to use a class instead of an array.

```
class point2 {
    private:
        float x_;
        float y_;
    public:
        point2(const float x, const float y): 
            x_{x}, y_{y} {};
        point2(const point2& o): 
            x_{o.x_}, y_{o.y_} {};

        operator = (const point2& o) {
            x_ = o.x_;
            y_ = o.y_;
        }
        // ...
};


point2 a = {90.0, 90.0}; // initialize a

a = {45.0, 45.0}; // untested, should work
a = point2{45.0, 45.0} // will work.
```

As you see, this will give you a more natural and expressive interface. Such interfaces always improve readability and maintaiability.

Comment: A great idea in general but perhaps not so convenient if you primarily want to pass the point to a third-party library that is expecting a pointer to an array. Which is the case here. You could have a `point2` class that contains an array or `std::array` and provide convenience getters/setters for x and y.

Comment: Yes, in that case you can adapt the internal representation of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible during initialization only.
Use:

```
a[0]= - 66;
a[1] = -66;
```

However you can create temporary array and then copy it.

```
point2 tmp = {-66, -66 }
System.arraycopy( tmp, 0, a, 0, src.length );
```

But it looks like an overkill for such a task.

Comment: Hm, okay. I know that I can do this in your way, but I was hoping that maybe there is more convenient way. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like:

```
a[0] =-66;
a[1]=-66;
```